# VTD XML parsing. Get value based on tag and attribute

Tags: xpath, vtd-xml

I have a bit complex XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><test:mark><parent parent_id="1"><child child_id="1_1">11Value</child><child child_id="1_2">12Value</child><child child_id="1_3">13Value</child></parent><other other_id="1"><inner>1233</inner></other></test:mark>
```

I am very new to VTD and now instead of parsing entire XML by DOM or SAX I want to get the value of `<child child_id="1_2">`

Can anyone suggest what XPATH expression can be used. Thanks in advance for the help. Other better options are welcome as well.

Below is what I am doing. And is not working!!

```
VTDGen vtdGen = new VTDGen();
        vtdGen.parseFile("E:/JavaProjects/SampleTestingFiles/SampleXML.xml", true);

        VTDNav vtdNav = vtdGen.getNav();
        AutoPilot autoPilot = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);

        try {
            autoPilot.selectXPath("//parent/child[@child_id='1_2']");
            if(autoPilot.evalXPathToBoolean()) {
                int token = autoPilot.evalXPath();
                if(token != -1) {
                    String value = vtdNav.toNormalizedString(token);
                    System.out.println("The value is - " + value);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If I do something like `autoPilot.selectXPath("//parent/child[@child_id]");`. It selects some of the tags with attribute `@child_id` but not all.

Any help is much appreciated even the documentation on how we should give XPATHs can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath evaluation logic not correct (your xpath expression seems ok)...

```
if(autoPilot.evalXPathToBoolean()) {
                int token = autoPilot.evalXPath();
                if(token != -1) {
                    String value = vtdNav.toNormalizedString(token);
                    System.out.println("The value is - " + value);
                }
            }
```

should be rewritten as

```
int i=-1;
while((i=autoPilot.evalXPath())!=-1){
              String value = vtdNav.toNormalizedString(i);
              System.out.println("The value is - " + value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 

I am getting bit confused on why we need while loop and not if condition if at all we are not shifting node and there is no change in `i`. Somehow I am finding it difficult to understand.

Comment: Also tested with 
`int i=-1;
while((i = autoPilot.evalXPath()) == -1) {
      String value = vtdNav.toNormalizedString(i);

 System.out.println("The value is - " + value);
}`

But still it is not going in while loop. As I am using Java  
`int i=-1;
while((i=autoPilot.evalXPath())=-1){
              String value = vtdNav.toNormalizedString(i);
              System.out.println("The value is - " + value);
}` is not getting compiled.

Comment: Thanks a lot. With the fix now it is giving value as `Child` but not `12Value`.

Comment: append text() to the expression, and you will get it

Comment: Awesome. Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Posting the final working after adding text

`VTDGen vtdGen = new VTDGen();
  vtdGen.parseFile("E:/JavaProjects/SampleTestingFiles/SampleXML.xml", true);
  
  VTDNav vtdNav = vtdGen.getNav();
  AutoPilot autoPilot = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
  
  try {
   autoPilot.selectXPath("//parent/child[@child_id='1_2']/text()");
   int i=-1;
   while((i=autoPilot.evalXPath())!=-1) {
    String value = vtdNav.toString(i);
    System.out.println("The value is - " + value);
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`